# jquery input value validation

Tags: jquery

How to validate when certain fields not filling?
I have few input with class="string" and submit button.

When user press button, display alert box, message with the name of field which not filled.

An example, if two fields not filling show alert with 2 string: fieldname1 not filled, fieldname2 not filled.

Comment: Try jQuery Plugin. "http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/"

Comment: this link is working: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(".string").each() should iterate through all elements with class string. Inside it tou can put some if that will be checking values of inputs ( if ($(this).val == ""){}), and you can store fieldnames inside some array or string.

Example:

```
var fields = "";

$(".string").each(function(index)
{
  if ($(this).val() == "")
  {
    fields += index + ";";
  }
});
alert (fields);
```

will show an alert with indexes of inputs that are not filled

Comment: and how call fieldnames array in this function?

Comment: Depends on your code - if you have every field in separate div, in which you have span for field name and input, then you can use $(this).parent().children('span').innerHTML. Or you can have set name attribute of input in which case you could use $(this).attr('name').

Comment: Oh. I do not know how to create the array using jQuery. Thanks for help.